# Does a relational schema need to be created for a one to many relationship?

Tags: sql, database

i was wondering if a schema needs to be created for a one to many relationship. Currently a beginner at databases. Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your design still implies two tables, so yes you need a schema for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little hard to answer - I will start by defining the terms.

A database **schema** is the complete [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema) of the database entitities and relationships. Some people talk about the "[logical schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_data_model)" - which focuses on the underlying concepts - and the "physical schema", which translates that to a specific database platform. Often, the logical schema will talk about entities and relationships, and the physical schema about tables, indexes and constraints.

For instance, your logical schema may say "there as a 1..n relationship between entities A and B" (often in a visual design tool), and your physical schema may say "table A uses a foreign key constraint to refer to table B" - not all databases support foreign key constraints.

Confusingly, some database engines (like Oracle) use the word "schema" as something close to the concept of "database".

So, the answer is yes - if you have entities or tables, they live within a schema (the complete definition of your database), just like 2 adjoining rooms with a door live within a building.